# Select element jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this structure in html:

```
<div class="accordion-heading low">

    <a class="accordion-toggle"></a> // I want to select this
    <div class="dropdown priority">
        <span></span>
        <a class="dropdown-toggle"></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="edit"></a></li> // from here
            <li>..</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

I want to select the `.accordion-toggle` class from the `<li>` with `.edit` class

I tried using closest:

```
$('.edit').on('click', function() {
     console.log( $(this).closest('a[class="accordion-toggle"]').text() );
});
```

I prints nothing.

How do I suppose to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the `accordion-toggle` is not a direct ancestor of the `edit` element, it is a sibling of one of the ancestor element

```
$('.edit').on('click', function() {
     console.log( $(this).closest('.accordion-heading').find('a.accordion-toggle').text() );
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3e78V/)

or

```
$('.edit').on('click', function() {
     console.log( $(this).closest('.dropdown').prev('.accordion-toggle').text() );
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nY4Dq/)